# Reservation Query In VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am making a reservation system and I want get available room details to DataGridView when making a new reservation. Room details are in one table called `service` and the reservation details are in `items_reserved` table. At each reservation I need to check for the date and time both.

The following query works well if I only consider date:

```
"SELECT * FROM Service " &
"WHERE Service_Type_ID= '" & txtBoxSerType.Text & "'" &
"  AND Service_ID NOT IN (" &
"          SELECT Service_ID FROM Items_Reserved" &
"          WHERE Date_In <= '" & DateTimePickerDateOut.Text & "'" &
"            AND Date_Out >= '" & DatePickerDateIn.Text & "'" &
"            AND Status Is Null" &
"      )"
```

But I need to check the time constraint also. The following query is what I tried but unfortunately it's not working:

```
"SELECT * FROM Service " &
"WHERE Service_Type_ID= '" & txtBoxSerType.Text & "'" &
"  AND Service_ID NOT IN (" &
"          SELECT Service_ID FROM Items_Reserved" &
"          WHERE Date_In <= '" & DateTimePickerDateOut.Text & "'" &
"            AND Date_Out >= '" & DatePickerDateIn.Text & "'" &
"            AND Status Is Null" &
"            AND Service_ID Not In (" &
"                    SELECT Service_ID FROM Items_Reserved" &
"                    WHERE Date_In = '" & DateTimePickerDateOut.Text & "'" &
"                      AND Time_In <= '" & DateTimePickerTimeOut.Text & "'" &
"                      AND Status Is Null" &
"                      AND Service_ID Not In (" &
"                              SELECT Service_ID FROM Items_Reserved" &
"                              WHERE Date_Out = '" & DatePickerDateIn.Text & "'" &
"                                AND Time_Out >='" & DateTimePickerTimeIn.Text & "'" &
"                                AND Status Is Null" &
"                          )" &
"                )" &
"      )"
```

For example, say that there is a reservation for `Room1` where:

- `DateIn  = 11/15/2015` and
- `DateOut = 11/17/2015` and
- `TimeIn  = 12:00` and
- `TimeOut = 14:00`

And when I use the second query given, and enter new reservation details to check available rooms as:

- `DateIn  = 11/17/2015` and
- `DateOut = 11/20/2015`
- `TimeIn  = 18:00` and
- `TimeOut = 08:00`

Ideally `Room1` should be shown as available.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Do you get an error? Do you not get the results you want? Some sample data and expected output would probably help. Also, **[USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES!!](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)** Sorry to shout but I cannot stress enough how important it is.

Comment: Define "not working".  How exactly does it fail?  What is the query that you're even using?  (Given all of those SQL injection vulnerabilities, your users could be executing literally *any* code they want on your database.)

Comment: If you use paramterised queries you can then use the `Value` of the dateTimePicker which is a date/time and so avoids any ambiguity in dates between locales

Comment: Say that there is a reservation for Room1 where DateIn = 11/15/2015 and DateOut = 11/17/2015 and TimeIn = 12:00 and TimeOut = 14:00. And when I use the second query given, and enter new reservation details to check available rooms as dateIn = 11/17/2015 and DateOut = 11/20/2015 TimeIn = 18:00 and TimeOut = 08:00, Ideally Room1 should be shown as available. But with this query Room1 is still unavailable, yes I will use parameterised query.thank you

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ And as @GarethD says, parameterize those queries immediately if not sooner.

Comment: Print your query with the variable, try it directly in the database. It'll help you debug it. Also, use parameters.

Comment: I am already doing it in database and could not find a solution even I work around it for almost two days

Comment: I made two edits to your question. Apart from spelling and formatting improvements and adding the clarification from your comment (you should use the [edit] link to improve your post), I also added linebreaks to your code to make it more readable. In the second edit, I rewrote your string concatenation to also make the query readable. If you think the last edit was incorrect or otherwise inappropriate, feel free to visit the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33806429/revisions) and rollback the post to revision 2, or [edit] the post to fix any errors I may have introduced.